# How to get the IP address of the request to a Heroku app?

Tags: python, heroku, flask, ip-address

Heroku has a routing system to forward requests to the dynos. My application needs to know from where the request came, but it always gets random addresses in a network, probably Heroku's internals.

And I see that in the logs, it (Heroku's router) gets my IP address and forwards the request. Is there a way to get the actual IP address of a request?

My application is written in Python, using Flask

Comment: probably `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` server variable.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking Flask's documentation on filtering headers etc., I found that:

```
request.headers['X-Forwarded-For']
```

is where you'll get the client's real IP address.

---

From a deleted comment by OP, this article provides a [safer solution](http://esd.io/blog/flask-apps-heroku-real-ip-spoofing.html).

Comment: @Leva7 As that post mentions, `X-Forwarded-For` gets a new IP appended for every forwarding. Which is why I did not pick up the first value returned. I am merely pointing out the header where you can find your client's real IP. How you want to actually parse it, is your own task. :) I'll although put the link you gave in my answer too.

Answer (score 1):

You want to preserve the IP from `request.remote_addr` when locally or if hosting the site somewhere else:

```py
def getIP():
    if 'X-Forwarded-For' in request.headers:
        return request.headers['X-Forwarded-For']
    return request.remote_addr
```